# Elastic OR-options its not working as I expected

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-query

Why should I do this to get all results based on my three terms:

```json
...
"must": [
  {
    "query_string": {
      "analyze_wildcard": true,
      "query": "* AND (name:\"NAME 1\" OR name:\"NAME 2\" OR name:\"NAME 3\")"
    }
  },
...
```

instead of

```json
...
"must": [
  {
    "query_string": {
      "analyze_wildcard": true,
      "query": "* AND name:\"NAME 1\" OR name:\"NAME 2\" OR name:\"NAME 3\""
    }
  },
...
```

The first query returns all docs with **NAME 1**, **NAME 2**, and **NAME 3**, but the second query returns only docs with the term **NAME 1**.

in addition, the query below returns only the **NAME 3**

```json
...
"must": [
  {
    "query_string": {
      "analyze_wildcard": true,
      "query": "name:\"NAME 1\" OR name:\"NAME 2\" OR name:\"NAME 3\" AND *"
    }
  },
...
```

It doesn't make sense, because if I create a query with a term that doesn't exist, such as: `" * AND name: \ "asdfasdfa \" OR name: \ "NAME 2 \" OR name: \ "NAME 3 \" "` , I will have an empty answer and thinking about code conditionals:

`true && false || true || true` is `true`

`true && (false || true || true)` also `true`

and,

`'a' && null || 'b' || 'c'` is `'b'`

`'a' && (null || 'b' || 'c')` also `'b'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a topic of [operands precedence](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boolean_operators). Quoting the docs (**bold** highlights added by myself):

> The familiar boolean operators `AND`, `OR` and `NOT` (also written `&&`, `||` and !) are also supported **but beware that they do not honor the usual precedence rules, so parentheses should be used whenever multiple operators are used together**.

So, in case of query#2, the original:

```sql
* AND name:\"NAME 1\" OR name:\"NAME 2\" OR name:\"NAME 3\"
```

is internally converted to the lucene query:

```sql
+*:* +name:\"name 1\" name:\"name 2\" name:\"name 3\"
```

As such, it **cannot** be understood as:

```sql
true && false || true || true
```

which, in the standard boolean logic, would indeed be equal to `true`.

**Long story short, use parentheses whenever applicable.**

---

*BTW, the terms in the lucene query were [lowercased](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/analyze-wildcard/5156/2?u=joesorocin) (analyzed be the `standard` analyzer) because you specified `analyze_wildcard:true`. This may or may not be exactly what you'd want so I thought it was worth mentioning!*